# Should I exclude Aurelia scripts folder in .gitignore?

Tags: git, aurelia

Should I put the /scripts folder of my Aurelia project in .gitignore, since as best as I can tell, they are rebuilt on each run anyway?

My .gitignore currently contains:

```
node_modules
jspm_packages
.idea
.DS_STORE
```

Should I add the following?

```
scripts
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you're talking about a private repo:
We don't check in any generated files, including the js files that visual studio generates which live beside the TypeScript files (we leave VS' transpile turned on even though the aurelia build creates the bundle). We didn't think there was enough of a benefit to keep those files in source control, see them in our pending changes, etc when we don't even work directly with them.

If you want to keep records of the generated files it's fine to check them in. Otherwise I wouldn't bother.

Comment: Why doesn't the .gitignore generated by `au new` contain this line? Seems like it should.

Answer (score 2):

By default we don't exclude the `scripts` folder from being checked in to git because the idea is that you will place other scripts (such as legacy scripts loaded via a `<script>` tag.

If you do not plan to do this, there's no harm in having git ignore this folder.