# Add 'scripts' folder to .gitignore in Aurelia project?

Tags: javascript, git, aurelia

I am noticing that Aurelia is building to the `scripts` directory in my CLI project. Is it safe to add this directory to .gitignore, or is there some reason to track changes to 'scripts' in Git?

Comment: Depending on what functions the scripts have, you might want to leave them in the repo. E.g.: you add a new member to your team, and said scripts might be required for your project to work. In which case, if they're not in the repo, he will bother one of you to transfer them to his computer.

Comment: OK, thanks. Currently there are only scripts from the Aurelia bundler, but I can see why other scripts might be kept in that directory. If you add your response as an answer, I will upvote (or mark as accepted answer).

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40249319/should-i-exclude-aurelia-scripts-folder-in-gitignore

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can safely add **scripts** to the `.gitignore` file.

---

Aurelia CLI uses the **scripts** folder to store the generated scripts (`vendor-bundle.js` and `app-bundle.js`).

- `vendor-bundle.js` is for libraries (e.g. `aurelia-binding`, `bluebird` and `jquery`).
- `app-bundle.js` is for all your HTML, CSS and JS files from the `src` folder combined in one JS file.

Because these files are renewed every time you run `au run` or `au bundle`, there is no need for them to be in version control.

Answer (score 3):

Depending on what functions the scripts have, you might want to leave them in the repo.

E.g.: you add a new member to your team, and said scripts might be required for your project to work. In which case, if they're not in the repo, he will bother one of you to transfer them to his computer.

---

**Edit:** If the scripts are automatically generated every time you build the project, or if they are downloaded via a packet-manager, then there is no need to leave them in the repository.

If this is the case, it's a safe bet you can add the folder to the .gitignore. If this is not the case, then it might be better to leave them in the repository.

This all depends on your project, where you are putting your scripts and how the frameworks work.

Comment: I will try to remember to mark this as the accepted answer, unless there is another answer that clearly indicates it is unnecessary to track 'scripts' in VCS.

Comment: See my edit, I've added a bit more information on the matter